# Suppose a unique a generates a cyclic subgroup of order. Show ax = xa. - Fraleigh p. 67 6.50

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, intuition, cyclic-groups

[image]

(1.) I don't understand [above](http://math.berkeley.edu/~ogus/old/Math_113/sol3.pdf). How do you magically envisage and envision to let $b = xax^{-1}$?

What I did was to start from the answer and see if I can get a chain of equivalences. $ax = xa \iff ax\color{darkcyan}{x^{-1}} = xa\color{darkcyan}{x^{-1}} \iff a = xax^{-1}$
$\begin{align} \Leftarrow or \iff a^2 & = (xax^{-1})^2 
\\ e & = \end{align} $.

Hence $ax = xa \Leftarrow e = (xax^{-1})^2.$ Hence if I sally forth from the $RHS$ to $LHS$ then I'm done?
 But I never used $a$ was unique?

(2.) What's the intuition? $ax = xa$ looks like commutativity. Hence  $G$ is Abelian?

**Update Jan. 7 2014:** The comments and answers involve 'center, 'conjugate' which aren't covered up to this time. I didn't know they are needed here. Hence I'll return. Are there simpler answers?

Comment: Your implication goes the wrong way.

Comment: You look at $b=xax^{-1}$ simply because the map $z \mapsto xzx^{-1}$ is an isomomorphism of $G$  and hence it preserves the order of the element.

Comment: Hint: conjugate elements have the same order! It shows that in fact $a \in Z(G)$, the center of $G$.

Comment: The words 'envisage' and 'envision' are very awkward here and possibly incorrect, and if you use them people are going to be confused (especially non-native English speakers, which this site is full of). Similar remarks apply to 'supernormal'. If you ask how to motivate writing $b=xax^{-1}$, readers will understand what you mean. This is the usual way students of mathematics ask the question you want to ask.

Comment: (I don't normally like to point out usage errors because it's slightly annoying, and I apologize, but you seem to be a native English speaker and this is not the only question where you use these words.)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: What's bungled? Don't hesitate to edit my question.

Comment: @Potato envision was suggested to me by someone else here. I'll have to find where.

Answer (score 2):

You're given $\;a\in G\;$ is **the unique** element of order $\;2\;$ in $\;G\;$ . Now, we have that

$$\forall\,x\in G\;,\;\;(xax^{-1})^2=xax^{-1}xax^{-1}=xa^2x^{-1}=xx^{-1}=1$$

so by the above uniqueness it *must be* that

$$xax^{-1}=a\iff xa=ax\;,\;\;\text{since it can not be}\;\;xax^{-1}=1\;\;\text{(why?)}$$

The above means that $\;a\in Z(G):=\{g\in G\;;\;gx=xg\;\;\forall\,x\in G\}=\;$ the group's **center**

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. $a \in G$ is the unique element of order 2 in G hence only $a^2 = e$. $xax^{-1} \neq a$ hence $xax^{-1} \neq e$. Is this right?

Comment: Did you flesh out why you magically considered $(xax^{-1})^2$ in your second line? I don't see how you envisaged or envisioned it. It feels supernormal.

Comment: I didn't @FrankMuer, but I can now: I used that (1) both an element and any of its conjugates have the same order, and (2) an element is central iff all it equals all its conjugates. As you can see, it wasn't an "out-of-the-blue" choice at all...:)

Comment: Thanks. I haven't been introduced to conjugates and centers up until now. I'll return here later.

Answer (score 0):

I fill in DonAntonio's answer here.

You're given $\;a\in G\;$ is **the unique** element of order $\;2\;$ in $\;G\;$ .

How do you envisage and envision to consider $(xax^{−1})^2$ here?
This magically cropped up in DonAntonio's answer.

$$\forall\,x\in G\;,\;\;(xax^{-1})^2=xax^{-1}xax^{-1}=xa^2x^{-1}=xx^{-1}=1$$

so by the above uniqueness of $a\in G$ it *must be* that

$$xax^{-1}=a\iff xa=ax\;,\;\;\text{since it can not be}\;\;xax^{-1}=1\;\;\color{darkorange}{\text{(why?)}}$$

The above means that $\;a\in Z(G):=\{g\in G\;;\;gx=xg\;\;\forall\,x\in G\}=\;$ the group's **center**

**Update on (why?)** Question postulates: $a \in G$ is the unique element of order 2 in G. Hence only $a^2 = e$. $xax^{-1} \neq a$ hence $xax^{-1} \neq e$. Is this right?

Comment: About your very last inequality: no, it is that $$xax^{-1}=1\iff a=x^{-1}x=1\;\;\text{but}\;\;a\neq 1\;\;\ldots$$